# "having to look at"

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

"Look how he's always flirting with every woman he meets. I'm so tired of having to look at his white teeth and slicked-back hair."

First of all, is "having to look at" the most natural thing to use here? Would it also be natural to just say: "I'm so tired of looking at..."?

Secondly, if no one is forcing the one speaking to look at him, why is it still natural to say "having to look at"?

Answer (score 1):

The "having to" part of this phrase is meant to convey or suggest a perceived intentional aspect of the person's presentation of themselves: you don't *have* to look at them, but it requires a deliberate choice not to, as their personal grooming seems to be designed to draw attention to themselves.